# ¿Como puedo declarar una memoria estatica c++?

Tags: c++

tengo este codigo quisiera saber que es lo que debería cambiar para poder utilizar el  ( -> ) en vez de utilizar el  ( punto ) creo que tengo que agregarle un new

```
Lista<Punto> pLista;

pLista.insetarFinal(Punto(8, 1));

pLista.insetarFinal(Punto(7, 2));

pLista.insetarFinal(Punto(1, 3));

pLista.insetarFinal(Punto(9, 4));

pLista.insetarFinal(Punto(4, 5));
```

Answer (score 3):

Lo dices mal: el caso que tú muestras, es una variable (o instancia) **no dinámica**. Lo que quieres hacer es **crear una instancia dinámica**.

Lo de estática ... significa otra cosa ;-)

Simple:

```
Lista<Punto> *pLista = new Lista< Punto >;

pLista->insetarFinal(Punto(8, 1));
pLista->insetarFinal(Punto(7, 2));
pLista->insetarFinal(Punto(1, 3));
pLista->insetarFinal(Punto(9, 4));
pLista->insetarFinal(Punto(4, 5));
```

En lugar de crear una *instancia*, creas un *puntero* y lo inicializas.

Recuerda que **no se destruirá** solo, tendrás que hacerlo tú *a mano* cuando ya no lo necesites mas:

```
Lista< Punto > *pLista = new Lista< Punto >;

...

delete pLista;
```

Comment: De aquí me surge una duda. ¿Con la finalización del programa se llegaría a destruir también?

Comment: @Víctor Por supuesto. Al finalizar el programa, este deja de existir. La memoria se limpia, los archivos se cierran. En C++, los destructores se llaman, pero no en el caso de mi respuesta. Se llamarían en el código que muestra la pregunta, con instancias **no** dinámicas.

Comment: @Víctor a lo comentado por trauma añadir que se libera la memoria peeeeero no se llama al destructor... si dejas recursos abiertos puede que no se cierren correctamente

Comment: ¿Recursos abiertos? Gracias por responder